# Screen.AllScreens bug and posting a WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, to a single WinForm application

Tags: c#, wmi, pinvoke

Firstly, sorry about the long post.

**Any suggestions as to how I can limit the publish scope of the WM_DISPLAYCHANGE message?**

Scenario:

`Screen.AllScreens` returns an array of coordinates and resolutions for all monitors detected on a client. If an application is started when the workstation is locked (during an overnight application restart), `Screen.AllScreens` returns only one element detailing a single screen with the dimensions of all the multiple monitors as one.

Subsequently, in this scenario, when a user unlocks the workstation, and starts using the application, an Infragistics control (UltraWinDock) that is being used does not allow dragging floating windows outside the primary screen due to the `Screen.AllScreens` property not returning the true monitor configuration for the system.  The Infragistics control actually looks at `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds`, but the `Screen.PrimaryScreen` property in turn calls the cached `Screen.AllScreens` array, which returns an enormous primary screen!

When the application is started normally (with the workstation unlocked), the control functions correctly.

The only means by which I can see that `Screen.AllScreens` is reset, and can be refreshed is via the `SystemEvents.DisplayChanging` event being raised, 
at which point the internal field is set to null. (`Screen.AllScreens` hooks into this event.) `Screen.AllScreens` will then repopulate the next time it is called.

From what I can determine, the `SystemEvents.DisplayChanging` event can be raised via a `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` WMI message.

The means by which I have managed a workaround is by calling:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);
```

with a parameter of [SM_CMONITORS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which represents the number of displays on the system.  This appears to always return the actual number of monitors present, regardless of whether the workstation is locked or not.

I then evaluate whether the length of `Screen.AllScreens` array is less than the result of `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS)` and if it is, I hook into the 
`SystemEvents.SessionSwitch` static event and check the `SessionSwitchEventArgs.Reason` property, for a value of `SessionUnlock`.
When the workstation is unlocked, this event is received and the condition satisfied, so I post a message using P/Invoke method

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

with the following args:

```
PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_DISPLAYCHANGE,UIntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero)
```

**This works very nicely and the desired result is acheived!**  `Screen.AllScreens` is reset and the Infragistics control functions correctly.

It looks to me like an obscure bug with `Screen.AllScreens` not re-evalutating itself when an application is started on a locked workstation, and then unlocked.

A rare issue, I acknowldege, but an issue nonetheless.

For the [WM_DISPLAYCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, lParam and wParam are described as:

***wParam***

- The new image depth of the display, in bits per pixel.

***lParam***

- The low-order word specifies the horizontal resolution of the screen.
- The high-order word specifies the vertical resolution of the screen.

I am sending in nulls `IntPtr.Zero` for these arguments, as I don't know what the actual values are at the time of sending the message.

My concern here is that I am broadcasting the `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` message across the entire system with null arguments, and that there may be processes running that consume the `WM_DISPLAYMESSAGE` and utilise the arguments.  I would like to hope that if null arguments are send, any consumers would ignore the arguments, but this is a very dangerous assumption to make.

Is there a way to send or post the message to only the application in question, and remove the risk of affecting other processes?

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
PostMessage(IntPtr.Zero, WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
PostMessage(this.Handle, WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
PostThreadMessage(AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId(), WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
```

**NOTES:**

- I don't have a great deal of experience with P/Invoke or WMI.
- Target Framework is .Net 3.5.
- I haven't seen any side effects to broadcasting a PostMessage of the `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` method as yet.
- I have already downloaded the source code for Infragistics, and pinpointed where the issue occurs in their code, and considered re-compiling the control to integrate a fix, but decided against this.  I have informed Infragistics of the issue, but cannot wait for a fix, and don't especially see it as an Infragistics issue, as it is `Screen.AllScreens` causing the issue.
- The application restart overnight is necessary, and cannot be changed to wait until a user logging on in the morning.
- I have created a test application that locks a user's workstation, restarts itself (the application, not the workstation), and evaluates the `Screen.AllScreens` property when the application is locked, and then another snapshot after I send the `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` method. I'd like to add a screenshot, but am not allowed to as am a new StackOverflow user!!!

Comment: Infragistics again, that company is a major bug factory.  Solve your real problem, dump them.  If you don't want to then find help at their support channels.

Comment: Yup, I agree, but unfortunately the decision to use the controls is out of my hands, and the support channels will take too long, although I have logged it with them.  What I simply(!) need to know how to use P/Invoke to PostMessage to a specific application.

Answer (score 1):

Probably late to give an answer here, but another option here would be to just P/Invoke the same call that AllScreens uses. Then you would get the actual value instead of the cached value that AllScreens is keeping. Take a look at: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumDisplayMonitors.html

If you are in WPF, could do something like what is posted here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41e0bf65-2e96-4d0f-98aa-2c0cf31aa493/wpf-application-controls-does-not-work-when-an-external-monitor-is-connected?forum=wpf

Basically, find the SystemResourceNotifyWindow and post a WM_DISPLAYCHANGE message to it.

Answer (score 0):

> What I simply(!) need to know how to use P/Invoke to PostMessage to a specific application

You need to get the hwnd of the app, not:

```
SendMessage(this.Handle...
```

Find out the window class of the app using spy++, then use FindWindow() to get its hwnd.

But there is probably something I'm missing here -- you seem plenty competent enough to realize that, so perhaps I am misunderstanding and that is code you have inside your recompiled Infragistics app?