# System.Windows.Forms.Screen is not updating after a display change

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, screen

As the title says, `System.Windows.Forms.Screen` is not properly updating its members after a display change. I'll concrete:

I have two monitors, and I programmatically swap the primary monitor between, by using [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsexa) function. When I swap the monitor, `SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` event is raised, and I can also see the change takes effect in the Windows control panel (I mean the checkbox that is enabled or disabled to make a monitor the primary monitor), however, in my application, the `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen` object remains the same as it was before swapping the primary monitor.

I come to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901247/screen-allscreens-bug-and-posting-a-wm-displaychange-to-a-single-winform-applic) thread from someone that noticed the same, and as seen in the [Screen class source-code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/compmod/microsoft/win32/SystemEvents.cs.html#c74f209379d151c3) it should renew/update the screen objects when intercepting a [WM_DISPLAYCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-displaychange) message, so I tried these calls:

```vb
Const HWND_BROADCAST As Integer = &HFFFF
Const WM_DISPLAYCHANGE As Integer = &H7e

PostMessage(New IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST), WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
SendMessage(New IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST), WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
```

But it does not seem to work, or maybe I'm not calling it with the right lParam and wParam, because `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen` object remains the same after sending the message to all windows, and `SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` event is raised after these calls.

In C# or VB.NET, I need to detect the REAL primary monitor after I swap them, after a display change.

Because I'm working with the `Screen` class when swapping monitors instead of using Windows API to enumerate monitors, is there any way I could work around the `Screen` class, maybe via **Reflection** or dispatching **WM_DISPLAYCHANGE**, to get a fresh/updated `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen` object after a display change?.

UPDATE

I also found another proof of evidence [on MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/345f91a9-30b4-4222-845d-a4ed5d0fb36d/c-screenallscreens-not-updating-changes-in-display-resolutionposition-not-reflected-in-screen) concerning this ...bug?. Note that thread from 2012 and no solution provided...

---

I share the (partial, relevant) code, as requested in the comments.

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Sets the specified <see cref="Screen"/> as primary.
''' <para></para>
''' This functionality will work only with a setup of two monitors. 
''' This functionality does not support three or more monitors.
''' </summary>
''' 
''' <param name="scr">
''' The new primary <see cref="Screen"/>.
''' </param>
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Shared Sub SetPrimaryScreen(scr As Screen)

    If (Screen.AllScreens.Count = 1) Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("There is only one available monitor.")
    End If

    If (Screen.AllScreens.Count > 2) Then
        Throw New NotSupportedException("Three or more monitor setups are not supported.")
    End If

    If scr.Equals(Screen.PrimaryScreen) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '' DIRTY FIX:
    ' If scr.IsRealPrimaryScreen() Then
    '     Exit Sub
    ' End If

    Dim scrPrimary As Screen = (Screen.AllScreens().Where(Function(s As Screen) s.Primary)).Single()

    '' DIRTY FIX:
    ' Dim scrPrimary As Screen = (Screen.AllScreens().Where(Function(s As Screen) s.IsRealPrimaryScreen())).Single()

    ' Set current primary device position.
    Dim setPositionPrimary As New DevMode(initializeSize:=True) With {.Fields = DeviceModeFields.Position}
    setPositionPrimary.Mode.DisplayDevMode.Position.X = scr.Bounds.Width
    setPositionPrimary.Mode.DisplayDevMode.Position.Y = 0
    NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(scrPrimary.DeviceName, setPositionPrimary, IntPtr.Zero, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.UpdateRegistry Or ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.NoReset, IntPtr.Zero)

    ' Set secondary device position, and set it as the new primary device.
    Dim setPositionSecondary As New DevMode(initializeSize:=True) With {.Fields = DeviceModeFields.Position}
    setPositionSecondary.Mode.DisplayDevMode.Position.X = 0
    setPositionSecondary.Mode.DisplayDevMode.Position.Y = 0
    NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(scr.DeviceName, setPositionSecondary, IntPtr.Zero, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.SetPrimary Or ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.UpdateRegistry Or ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.Reset, IntPtr.Zero)

    ' Update current primary device.
    Dim currentPrimary As New DevMode(initializeSize:=True)
    NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(scrPrimary.DeviceName, currentPrimary, IntPtr.Zero, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.UpdateRegistry Or ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.NoReset, IntPtr.Zero)

    ' Set secondary device as current primary device.
    Dim newPrimary As New DevMode(initializeSize:=True)
    NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(scr.DeviceName, newPrimary, IntPtr.Zero, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.SetPrimary Or ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.UpdateRegistry Or ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.NoReset, IntPtr.Zero)

End Sub
```

Usage example to swap monitors (in a two monitors setup):

```vb
Dim secondaryMonitor As Screen = (Screen.AllScreens().Where(Function(s As Screen) Not s.Primary)).Single()
SetPrimaryScreen(secondaryScreen)
```

That cannot be called twice within the same running app, because `Screen.PrimaryScreen` is not updated after the first change, so in subsequent calls to `SetPrimaryScreen` method, it processes bad the false/non-updated `Screen.PrimaryScreen`, I mean because `Screen.PrimaryScreen` always remains the same object pointing to the same device even after ceasing to be the primary device.

Note that the `SetPrimaryScreen` method has an error-handling to terminate execution if trying to set the `Screen.PrimaryScreen` as the primary screen (because it is already supposed to be the primary screen... but it is not, because `Screen.PrimaryScreen` object is not properly refreshed).

---

Note that I'm in search of a simple, natural, optimal solution, but I already managed to figure a workaround for all this in a dirty way by creating a extension method for `Screen` class with name `IsRealPrimaryScreen` that I will use instead of the default `Screen.Primary` property.

```vb
<HideModuleName>
Public Module ScreenExtensions

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determine whether the source <see cref="Screen"/> is the primary device.
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' You must always call <see cref="ScreenExtensions.IsRealPrimaryScreen"/> function 
    ''' instead of <see cref="Screen.Primary"/>, 
    ''' which does not properly update the class members after a display change:
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' <see href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67061729/system-windows-forms-screen-is-not-updating-after-a-display-change"/>
    ''' <para></para>
    ''' <see href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901247/screen-allscreens-bug-and-posting-a-wm-displaychange-to-a-single-winform-applic"/>
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <example> This is a code example.
    ''' <code language="VB.NET">
    ''' Dim primaryMonitor As Screen = (Screen.AllScreens().Where(Function(scr As Screen) scr.IsRealPrimaryScreen)).Single()
    ''' Dim secondaryMonitor As Screen = (Screen.AllScreens().Where(Function(s As Screen) Not s.IsRealPrimaryScreen)).First()
    ''' Console.WriteLine(primaryMonitor.DeviceName)
    ''' Console.WriteLine(secondaryMonitor.DeviceName)
    ''' </code>
    ''' </example>
    ''' <param name="scr">
    ''' The source <see cref="Screen"/>.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' <see langword="True"/> if the source <see cref="Screen"/> is the primary device;
    ''' <see langword="False"/> otherwise.
    ''' </returns>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    <Extension>
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
    Public Function IsRealPrimaryScreen(scr As Screen) As Boolean

        Dim result As Boolean

        Dim callback As Delegates.EnumMonitorProc =
        Function(hMonitor As System.IntPtr, hdc As System.IntPtr, ByRef rc As NativeRectangle, data As System.IntPtr) As Boolean

            Dim mi As New MonitorInfoEx(initializeSize:=True)
            NativeMethods.GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, mi)

            If (mi.DeviceName.Equals(scr.DeviceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) Then
                result = mi.Flags.HasFlag(MonitorInfoFlags.PrimaryDevice)
                Return False
            End If

            Return True
        End Function

        NativeMethods.EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, callback, IntPtr.Zero)

        Return result

    End Function

End Module
```

And a `GetRealPrimaryScreen` method that I will use to get a `Screen` instance of the primary device instead of using `Screen.PrimaryScreen`:

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Gets a <see cref="Screen"/> object that represents the primary device.
''' <para></para>
''' You must always call <see cref="DeviceUtil.GetRealPrimaryScreen"/> function 
''' instead of <see cref="Screen.PrimaryScreen"/>, 
''' which does not properly update the class members after a display change:
''' <para></para>
''' <see href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67061729/system-windows-forms-screen-is-not-updating-after-a-display-change"/>
''' <para></para>
''' <see href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901247/screen-allscreens-bug-and-posting-a-wm-displaychange-to-a-single-winform-applic"/>
''' </summary>
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code language="VB.NET">
''' Dim primary As Screen = GetRealPrimaryScreen()
''' Console.WriteLine(primary.DeviceName)
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' <returns>
''' The resulting <see cref="Screen"/> object.
''' </returns>
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Shared Function GetRealPrimaryScreen() As Screen

    Dim result As Screen = Nothing

    Dim callback As Delegates.EnumMonitorProc =
    Function(hMonitor As IntPtr, hdc As IntPtr, ByRef rc As NativeRectangle, data As IntPtr) As Boolean

        Dim mi As New MonitorInfoEx(initializeSize:=True)
        NativeMethods.GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, mi)

        If mi.Flags.HasFlag(MonitorInfoFlags.PrimaryDevice) Then
            result = DeviceUtil.GetScreenFromDeviceName(mi.DeviceName)
            Return False
        End If

        Return True
    End Function

    NativeMethods.EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, callback, IntPtr.Zero)

    Return result

End Function
```

Comment: Are you setting the `CDS_SET_PRIMARY` and  `CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY` (and possibly `CDS_RESET`) Flags? You shouldn't need to broadcast the change, IIRC `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()` does that on its own. -- You should probably post your code.

Comment: Have you tried to send WM_REFLECT + WM_DISPLAYCHANGE https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/win32/SystemEvents.cs,1514

Comment: @Jimi I added the relevant code. Yes you will se I'm using the CDS_RESET flag in one or two of the calls, because otherwise I noticed the change does not take effect.

Comment: @Simon Mourier Yes, I've tried something like: `PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_REFLECT + WM_DISPLAYCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)`

Comment: I also found another proof of evidence on MSDN concerning this bug?: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/345f91a9-30b4-4222-845d-a4ed5d0fb36d/c-screenallscreens-not-updating-changes-in-display-resolutionposition-not-reflected-in-screen that is from 2012 and no solution provided... I think I'm lucky to have figured out a dirty workaround at least.